# Upload file to specific folder in sharepoint from local machine using c#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Hi previously i have asked for a question and i have sorted the answer for it [Upload a file in SharePoint server from a local machine connected through LAN using c#](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/154097/upload-a-file-in-sharepoint-server-from-a-local-machine-connected-through-lan-us/154250#154250) .But unfortunately the files are not getting uploaded into Shared Documents (ie) i want the file to get upload under the shared document of the logged in user (eg) in this path

> http://sharepoint/my/personal/admin/Shared%20Documents/

but now it not getting uploaded in the above path , its getting uploaded in

> http://10.0.0.13:48487/Shared%20Documents
>   and also i can only able to access the files in above path by manually entering the URL in address bar .!

I want my file to get upload under the personal/my content/shared Document of the logged in user .!

**NOTE :** i was pointing the shared socument in c# while uploading the file using
`SP.List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Document");`

If i tried giving the full url in cliecntContext its throwing exception as

> Cannot contact site at the specified URL http://sharepoint/my/personal/admin/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx. There is no Web named "/my/personal/admin/Shared

Comment: Did you try giving Site URL as your my site URL in `ClientContext`? Because if you give your my site URL in it, it will only upload to that `Shared Document` library only.

Comment: if i tried giving full url it throws exception

Comment: `ClientContext` will not find any web if you give full url. You need to give url till `admin`, for example `http://sharepoint/my/personal/admin`. Not the full url with document library name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are retrieving the `ClientContext` object for your my site only.

For example you can try this code snippet:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint/my/personal/admin");
```

This will load your context of `admin` site web only, so that you can successfully find the document library and upload the file in it.

Comment: but it always uploading 2 versions :O why its so @Pradip R

Comment: Well, it should not upload 2 versions, there might be some code defects in it. I would suggest you to debug the code and check why you are seeing two versions.

Comment: I checked...But i couldn't find any issue in the code

Comment: R here is my code..! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/154250/45380